# How can I properly set the Extended Permissions node in the manifest.xml?

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am currently trying to use the appendOnSendAsync API call for Outlook and I am getting the error: "Extended Permission missing from API call" with error code: 9074. I have the extended permissions set the way I see it in the documentation. However, it is still unable to recognize that it is there. Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" 
  xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>a5afbf03-dcfc-435c-8a7b-02f37f162796</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="No-Framework"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="A template to get started."/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.contoso.com/help"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>contoso.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.8"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read"/>
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>true</DisableEntityHighlighting>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
          <DesktopFormFactor>
            <SupportsSharedFolders>true</SupportsSharedFolders>
            <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url"/>
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Events">
              <Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" FunctionName="action" />
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>
      <Resources>
        <bt:Urls>
          <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html"/>
        </bt:Urls>
        <bt:ShortStrings>
          <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Contoso Add-in"/>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane"/>
          <bt:String id="ActionButton.Label" DefaultValue="Perform an action"/>
        </bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:LongStrings>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying all available properties."/>
          <bt:String id="ActionButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Perform an action when clicked."/>
          <bt:String id="AppendOnSend" DefaultValue="AppendOnSend"/>
        </bt:LongStrings>
      </Resources>
      <ExtendedPermissions>
        <ExtendedPermission>AppendOnSend</ExtendedPermission>
      </ExtendedPermissions>
    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

My Outlook version is: Version 2006 (Build 12914.20000) Office Insider

Comment: There are many pre-requisites for this to work, according to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/preview-requirement-set/outlook-requirement-set-preview, although how to determine if something is missing?  Any link in AppDomains needs to be fully qualified with the protocol.  If you are making any change to the manifest, please increase the version number or change the GUID, otherwise Outlook may not download an updated manifest.  Try with browser instead - it is easier to troubleshoot. Did you use beta link to Outlook JS? Are your updated scripts loading?

Comment: What version of Exchange are you connected to? Detailed documentation of the steps required to use appendOnSend can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/append-on-send?tabs=windows

Comment: Hey I actually got it to work with the help of a button, the issue I am now having was with how I am using ItemSend Event to appendOnSend a message

Comment: What issues are you seeing? AppendOnSend does not need to be run from an ItemSend Event. AppendOnSend can be run at any time, and it will append text at the time of send. Detail of this API's functionality can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.body?view=outlook-js-preview#appendonsendasync-data--options--callback-

Comment: Oh, that makes sense, I want AppendOnSend to run anytime before the email is sent without the user explicitly clicking an add-in button to activate the event. That is why I was trying to run it from the ItemSend event which seems to fail. I am getting the error: OSF.DDA.AsyncResult {value: undefined, status: "failed", error: OSF.DDA.Error}, when I try to run it in Outlook for Web.

Comment: Based on your use case it seems like you don't necessarily need to call this from itemsend event. If that's correct, may we assume that you're unblocked now?

Comment: Well actually, my original idea was to use the ItemSend Event to call the AppendOnSend, however, that is the part that it keeps failing on

Comment: We are still looking into the itemsend aspect of it however, from your explanation it seems like it's not a requirement for you to be calling that from the itemsend event and you could use it without the itemsend event to achieve your scenario? Is our understanding correct?

Comment: Yep, this is correct